# Serialize xml into a custom class and then add the value to an observable collection

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How I serialize the data into xml , XBMC is my custom class.

```
private static XBMC LoadXbmcShows(string XMlFile)
{
    XBMC XBMCSShowsList;
    TextReader Reader = new StreamReader(XMlFile);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XBMC));
    XBMCSShowsList = (XBMC)serializer.Deserialize(Reader);
    Reader.Close();
    return XBMCSShowsList;
 }

XBMC XBMCSList = LoadXbmcShows(_XMLFile);
```

This is how I create the `ObservableCollection`:

```
readonly ObservableCollection<XBMC> myCollection
    = new ObservableCollection<XBMC>()

public ObservableCollection<XBMC> MyCollection
{ get { return myCollection; } }
```

I am just not sure how to add all the data from `XBMCSList` to the collection.
I am also happy to try do it a different way if any one has any ideas.

Code Behind for main window:

```
namespace MySQlXML
{  
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string _XMLFile = @"C:\Dump\test.xml";

        List<string> ToCopylist = new List<string>();

        readonly ObservableCollection<XBMC> myCollection
            = new ObservableCollection<XBMC>();

        public ObservableCollection<XBMC> MyCollection
        {
            get { return myCollection; }
        }


        public ObservableCollection<XBMC> MyCollection
        {
            get { return myCollection; }
        } 

        XBMC XBMCSList = LoadXbmcShows(_XMLFile);
        MyCollection.Add(XBMCSList);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Showlistbox.ItemsSource = XBMCSList.Show;
            //foreach (XBMCShow show in XBMCSList.Show)
            //{
            //    Showlistbox.Items.Add(show.ShowName);

            //}
        }

        private static XBMC LoadXbmcShows(string XMlFile)
        {
            XBMC XBMCSShowsList;

            TextReader Reader = new StreamReader(XMlFile);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XBMC));
            XBMCSShowsList = (XBMC)serializer.Deserialize(Reader);
            Reader.Close();

            return XBMCSShowsList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `XBMCSList` **one** `XBMC` or several? The variable name is a bit misleading

Comment: ps: with IDisposable objects (StreamReader is IDisposable), use the pattern using(var reader=new StreamReader(xmlfile)){... do sthng ...} 
That way, your reader will be closed & disposed even if deserialization threw an exception.

Comment: It is just one that if you like I can add the class definition and the contents of the xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean: How can I add the deserialization result to the list? Here is an example where I am deserializing and adding in the constructor:

```
private static XBMC LoadXbmcShows(string XMlFile)
{
  XBMC XBMCSShowsList;
  TextReader Reader = new StreamReader(XMlFile);
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XBMC));
  XBMCSShowsList = (XBMC)serializer.Deserialize(Reader);
  Reader.Close();
  return XBMCSShowsList;
}

readonly ObservableCollection<XBMCShow> myCollection = 
  new ObservableCollection<XBMCShow>()

public ObservableCollection<XBMCShow> MyCollection 
{ get { return myCollection; } }

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  XBMC XBMCSList = LoadXbmcShows(_XMLFile);
  myCollection = new new ObservableCollection<XBMCShow>(XBMCSList.Show);
  Showlistbox.ItemsSource = myCollection;
}
```

From a chat I got the definition for `XBMC`:

```
public partial class XBMC 
{ 
  private XBMCShow[] showField; 

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Show")] 
  public XBMCShow[] Show 
  { 
    get { return this.showField; } 
    set { this.showField = value; } 
  } 
}
```

.. and the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Showlistbox"> 
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowName}" /> 
    </DataTemplate> 
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yes that is what what I was trying to say , I tyed you code and it just says 'MySQlXML.MainWindow.MyCollection' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' and this error 'MySQlXML.MainWindow.XBMCSList' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Are you running these two lines in a method? Can you share the code?

Comment: No i just did this `readonly ObservableCollection<XBMC> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<XBMC>()
     
        public ObservableCollection<XBMC> MyCollection
        {
            get { return myCollection; }
        } 
        
        XBMC XBMCSList = LoadXbmcShows(_XMLFile);
        MyCollection.Add(XBMCSList);`

Comment: You have to do it in a method or constructor or something and not directly in a class amongst properties and fields!

Comment: Ok I added the code behind for ht main window so you can see what is going on

Comment: I adjusted my answer: Do it in the constructor and you are fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38328/discussion-between-justinf-and-meilke)